# Stack around variable "struc" is corrupted

Tags: c, stack

So I'm facing a problem with Visual Studio 2013
This code shows no compilation errors but a debug error

> Stack around the variable 'Joueur' was corrupted.

This is the code:

== Source.cpp

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "Header.h"

int main()
{
    Personne Joueur[2];
    printf("***** Bienvenue ***** \n \n \n");
    int k ;
    for (k = 0; k < 3; k++)
    {
        printf("Bonjour Joueur %d :\n", k+1);
        printf("Nom: ");
        fgets(Joueur[k].Nom,50,stdin);
        printf("Votre nom est: %s", &Joueur[k].Nom);
        printf("\n \n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

== Header.h

```
typedef struct Personne Personne;
struct Personne
{
    char Nom[1500];
    char Prenom[1500];
    int Age;
    int Tel;
    double Moy;
};
```

Comment: `Personne Joueur[2]; ...
    for (k = 0; k < 3; k++)` --> `Personne Joueur[3];`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change `Personne Joueur[2]; -> Personne Joueur[3];`

You do not have enough memory to hold more than 2 structures.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to more values into `Joueur[2]` than memory. So, there is not enough memory to hold the more then two values.

You are overrunning the allocated memory and it invokes **undefined behaviour**. So, Define a array bigger enough to hold the values. SO, change your array value according to **sas** answer.